# Vue js in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js

I'm struggling to implement a simple Vue.js app into Cordova. Everything works fine except that I don't know how I can intercept cordova events (deviceready, pause, ...) into my vue application. I used the Webpack template from vue-cli.

Here's my file `js/index.js` :

```
const app = {
  initialize: function () {
    console.log('initialize')
    this.bindEvents()
  },
  bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false)
  },
  onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready')
  },
  receivedEvent: function (id) {
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id)
  }
}

app.initialize()
```

the `src/main.js` :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
const app = new Vue({
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})

app.$mount('#app')
```

config/index.js :

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    //assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css']
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8080,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

webpack.base.conf.js :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
      'semantic': path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.js')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        // jquery
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        semantic: 'semantic-ui-css',
        'semantic-ui': 'semantic-ui-css'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        include: projectRoot,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({ sourceMap: useCssSourceMap }),
    postcss: [
      require('autoprefixer')({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.prod.conf :

```
var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    loaders: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap, extract: true })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin(utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    })
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}
```

And here's my project structure :

[image: app structure]

What shoud I do to get events from Cordova to my Vue components ?

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Are these two 'app' vars conflicting with each other?

Comment: I'm not receiving any error, but I don't get the `deviceready`events. What I think I should do is when I received the event `deviceready`, I instantiate my Vue app but the event never fire

Comment: Is `index.js` or `main.js` loaded into the page first? Are you running this on a physical device or in the browser (you need the cordova compile process on a device to include cordova.js). Trying moving your cordova initialization code around, and IDK if you know this but your cordova initialization code is only printing to console right now (not initializing Vue). Also, in general it is a bad idea to name everything app/index/main.

Comment: My Webpack entry is `'./src/main.js'`. I'm running this mainly in browser and test it from time to time on a physical android device. I'm aware that the cordova init code doesn't instantiate my vue app but i'm not able to catch any events from cordova

Comment: Yeah cordova events won't fire in browser. Tried recently on a device?

Comment: But how can i develop my app in browser (for convenience) if i need a cordova event to launch it ? I just tried on a physical device with chrome devtools remote and any of the events are fired (i get any console.log), thanks !

Comment: Sure thing friend. I added an answer with descriptions on how you can do that. Check it out & accept it when you're ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that Cordova.js is not included in browser, you need to test on a physical device.

That doesn't mean you can't prototype in the browser though. In JS, `window.cordova` will be defined if cordova has loaded. So you can setup your initialization like so

```
if(window.cordova){
  //add deviceready event to start app
} else {
  //call starting function
}
```

For things requiring a physical device: vibration, accelerometer, etc, you have to build and deploy to a device, the browser itself is not enough.

Comment: Seems like cordova isn't loaded on build (chrome remote devtools tells me that window.cordova is not set), added webpack config to question as it might be related

Comment: `window.cordova` will be defined on the device, where the cordova build process includes the `cordova.js` file. It will be undefined in the browser where `cordova.js` is missing. You can check to see if it's defined and create programming paths for each instance, waiting on deviceready if its definied, or document ready if it is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

See this article, it worked for me:

https://coligo.io/building-a-mobile-app-with-cordova-vuejs/

To allow the app to access the Vue.js library, we also need to add the following to the end of the Content Security Policy (CSP) meta tag in www/index.html:

```
; script-src 'self' http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js 'unsafe-eval'
```